# perl oo dynamic methods

Tags: perl, object, dynamic, methods

I'd like to define methods inside a class dynamically. I'm writing a tracer, somewhat more complex than the skeleton below, its also state aware but that is not relevant to my problem. 
I've written a TraceSlave class with trace method that calls sprintf, replaces newlines with text \n, all good and nice.

Basically I'd like to instantiate my trace as:

```
my @classes = qw(debug token line src match);
my $trace = Tracer->new(\@classes);
```

And I should be able to call the dynamically defined methods of trace as:

```
$trace->debug("hello, world");
$trace->match("matched (%s)(%s)(%s)(%s)(%s)", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5);
```

So my Tracer class would look like:

```
package Tracer;
  sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    my @traceClasses = @{$_[0]};
    bless $self, $class;
    for (@traceClasses) {
# This next line is wrong, and the core of my question
      $self->$_ = new TraceSlave($_, ...)->trace
    } # for (@traceClasses)
  }
```

Well it doesn't because that doesn't compile. Basically I want to define methods of the Tracer instance, as the trace method of instances of TraceSlave; in a loop.

I could do it with AUTOLOAD, or eval but that's just wrong. What's the right way?

Here's the TraceSlave for completeness. It's fine

```
package TraceSlave;
  sub new {
    my $self = { header => $_[1], states => $_[2], stateRef => $_[3] };
    bless $self, $_[0];
    return $self;
  } # new()

  sub trace {
    my $self = shift;
    my @states = @{$self->{states}};
    if ($states[${$self->{stateRef}}]) { # if trace enabled for this class and state
      my @args;
      for (1..$#_) { ($args[$_-1] = $_[$_]) =~ s/\n/\\n/g; } # Build args for sprintf, and replace \n in args
      print $self->{header}.sprintf($_[0], @args)."\n";
    }
  } # trace()
```

Comment: what is wrong with `AUTOLOAD`? http://perldoc.perl.org/AutoLoader.html

Comment: I know the names of all methods I want. They were passed in. AUTOLOAD is for when you don't know the name of methods that might be called. Its got to be slower, and its sloppy, and its just not right (unless its the only way) for this. Isn't it mainly intended as an error handler? I feel eval would be less bad than AUTOLOAD. Also I would like to know how my understanding of perl references remains wrong.

Comment: `AUTOLOAD` should be slow only on first evocation per method. You could in this first call create method for all future method requests.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I start getting into runtime munging of classes I just start using MOP and Moose. So if I'm reading this right, you want something along the lines of

```
package Tracer;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;
use TraceSlave;

has 'classes' => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]', required => 1 );

### This is to allow ->new(\@classes) invocation instead of just
### using ->new( classes => \@classes) for invocation
around BUILDARGS => sub {
  my $orig  = shift;
  my $class = shift;

  if ( @_ == 1 && ref $_[0] eq 'ARRAY' ) {
    return $class->$orig( classes => $_[0] );
  }
  else {
    return $class->$orig(@_);
  }
};

sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;
  for my $class (@{$self->classes}) {
    my $tracer = TraceSlave->new($class, ...);
    $self->meta->add_method( $class => sub { $tracer->trace(@_) } );
  }
}
```

Though I'm fairly certain this just does the same thing under the hood and ends up being a string eval. I haven't dug into the MOP internals at all. (I'm also not 100% certain this is correct code or the best way to do things with Moose, so buyer beware. :) )

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the specifics of the 'tracer' problem, is it correct that you simply want to be able to dynamically create methods for a given package? What about this?

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $trace_classes) = @_;

    # ...

    foreach my $tc (@$trace_classes) {
        no strict 'refs';
        *{"${class}::${tc}"} = sub {
            my $self = shift;
            # ...
        };
    }

    return $self;
}
```

Although it seems *very* strange to do that in a `new`! So maybe I've missed the point

Comment: To clarify, this is almost certainly the wrong thing to be doing to solve your problem! What if I create multiple objects? Then the sub will be overwritten on each `new`. `AUTOLOAD` is probably better - although personally I would start reconsidering my approach at this point. If you're only ever creating one object, do you even need OO?

Nonetheless - I leave the above answer as how to dynamically create a sub without `eval`.

Comment: Thanks Unk, that's almost exactly what I wanted. I'm answering the question again because I can only seem to type comments in these small boxes. So please look below.

Comment: one more comment. You're absolutely right that the whole concept breaks if you have multiple Tracer instances because the class not the  instance is getting the dynamic methods. However if we had multiple Tracer instances they would all share the same IO device STDOUT which would also be rather messy. OO is still right because the Tracer instance needs a handle on trace states so it can switch tracing on or off. And the TraceSlave also needs a handle on these states so it can trace or not trace. I will have a parser using one set of trace classes, and a compiler a different set.

Comment: As the trace classes are simply a text string delimited by white space, the compiler can create the trace classes the parser needs, and give it the Tracer instance. As long as the parser and compiler don't try and share trace classes, which they won't. In other words yes OO with a single instance is right, and thanks for helping me dump the nasty eval.

Comment: If something has global effect, I'd prefer to be honest about that global effect. As it is, you are creating an API that gives the impression that I can create as many objects as I want. Even if *you* know the limitations / design decisions, someone else probably wouldn't. Whenever possible, you should aim for your API to 'guide' the consumer of it to the right usage.

Comment: Ok, valid criticism but: My current system achieves two excellent objectives: Complete encapsulation in one reference, and clean client interface: $trace->src(...). I don't think that could be achieved without OO, so what would be your best practice? I'm not being cynical, I do respect your knowledge.

Comment: Furthermore my final code above doesn't work. *{"${class}::$tc"} = sub { $slave->trace(@_[1..$#_]); }. The last created slave is always called. Obviously. eval allows me to create a unique handle. Assigning the lvalue directly to &$slave->trace would also work, but I can't get that to work. I think I'm learning perl fast, but sometimes I still feel illiterate!

Comment: Off the top of my head... I'd be tempted to create a module that could be used along the lines of: `use Trace qw/ debug token line src match /;` (creating the subs in an `import`) then called as `Trace->debug(...);` and so on. You can still encapsulate the state inside the package... But I'm on a bit of 'no unnecessary OO' kick at the moment - so feel free to ignore :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use string eval to define subroutines:

```
for my $method (@classes) {
    eval "sub $method { 'TraceSlave'->new('$method', ...)->trace }";
}
```

Comment: That is precisely what I'll do if I don't get a better answer. But surely there's a right way of doing it??? I'm a bit anal that way, right over simple.

Comment: @FrancisCagney: There is nothing "unright" in this method, if you know what is inside `@classes`.

Comment: I actually noted that both AUTOLOAD and eval would be solutions in my original post. But I wanted to know how to define class methods dynamically. I suppose I could just define a hash of methods and forget oo completely.

Comment: And there's something intrinsically wrong with eval instantiating the TraceSlave every time you want to call its trace method. For an embedded programmer like me such a waste of CPU cycles is outrageous.

Comment: @FrancisCagney: Oh, if you just want one instance of TraceSlave for each method, you can instantiate it before the eval.

Comment: why string eval? using glob types as in perldoc should be better?

Comment: @mpapec: Depends on how complicated the subroutine is.

Comment: I'd love to know how to use glob types the achieve this. But my understanding is that globs can be used to simultaneously assign a $scalar,%hash,@array,&sub if they all have the same name. I want to assign only a reference to a sub to a class member name, where the class member names are parameters to the instance creator. I've solved it using eval, and will post my solution for criticism/admiration/mirth in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've finished my little module, and learnt an awful lot about references. I am defining methods dynamically, but using eval which I consider very dirty. However nobody seems to have a better idea so here it is.

The line that creates the dynamic methods is just after the comment: # Very dirty creation of dynamic method, surely there's a better way?

So I'd still be interested in hearing of a better way. As somebody said I could use Moose, but Moose would just have done an eval for me anyway.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package TraceSlave;
  sub new {
    my $self = { header => $_[1], states => $_[2], stateRef => $_[3] };
    bless $self, $_[0];
    return $self;
  } # new()

  sub trace {
    my $self = shift;
    if ($self->{states}->[${$self->{stateRef}}]) {  # if trace enabled for this class and state
      my @args;
      for (1..$#_) { ($args[$_-1] = $_[$_]) =~ s/\n/\\n/g; } # Build args for sprintf, and replace \n in args
      print $self->{header}.sprintf($_[0], @args)."\n";
    }
  } # trace()

package Tracer;
  sub new {
    my ($class, $classList, $stateCount, $stateRef) = @_;
    my $self = { states => {}, slaves => [], count => $stateCount };
    my @classes = split(/\s+/, $classList);
    my $maxlen = 0;

    for (@classes) { # loop over all trace classes to find longest
      my $len = length($_);
      $maxlen = $len if $len > $maxlen;
    }
    $maxlen++; # Add a space

    for (0..$#classes) { # loop over all trace classes, and eval create a slave for each class
      my $tc = $classes[$_];
      my $states = $self->{states}->{$tc} = [];
      for (0..$stateCount) { $states->[$_] = 0; }
      $self->{slaves}[$_] = TraceSlave->new( "$tc:"." "x($maxlen-length($tc)), $states, $stateRef );
# Very dirty creation of dynamic method, surely there's a better way?
      eval("sub $tc { ".'$self=shift; $self->{slaves}['.$_.']->trace(@_); }');
    } # for (0..$#classes)
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
  } # new()

  sub _onOff { # switch on traces
    my ($self, $onOff, $classList, $statesRef) = @_;
    my @classes = split(/\s+/, $classList);
    my $count = $self->{count};

    for (@classes) { # loop over all supplied trace classes and switch on/off for state list
      my $states = $self->{states}->{$_};
      if ($statesRef) { for (@$statesRef) { $states->[$_] = $onOff; } }
      else { for (0..$count) { $states->[$_] = 1; } } # switch on for all states is no state list
    } # for (0..$#classes)
  } # on()

  sub on {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->_onOff( 1, @_ );  
  }

  sub off {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->_onOff( 0, @_ );  
  }
1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the symbol table of your package to add methods to the class, you cannot have two instances with different semantics of a same named method. Using AUTOLOAD in this case seems perfectly fine to me.

regards, matthias

Comment: I don't understand this comment. If you look at the very top of this thread I explain that the methods created are named by the list passed into new(). Each of these dynamically created methods does the same thing. trace or not trace via sprintf and a kinda chomp depending on state and trace classes. I know the names of all methods to be created so AUTOLOAD still seems wrong.

Comment: @FrancisCagney I think now I understand: You you know all method names and their behavior. You simply want to generate all needed methods, so that you do not have to write them. Is that correct? Then my comment is out of place. And now I see that this is already discussed in another comment by Unk.

Comment: Sort of. At the time of writing the Tracer it doesn't know it's dynamic methods. But the dynamic methods are passed as a string list to new().

Answer (score 0):

@Unk In answer to Unk's little code snippet above.

```
  foreach my $tc (@classes) { # loop over all trace classes, and create a slave for each class
    my $states = $self->{states}->{$tc} = [];
    $slave = TraceSlave->new( "$tc:"." "x($maxlen-length($tc)), $states, $stateRef );
    no strict 'refs';
    *{"${class}::$tc"} = sub { $slave->trace(@_[1..$#_]); }
  } # foreach my $tc (@classes)
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
} # new()
```

This is certainly much cleaner. I don't need to have slaves in the Tracer $self any more.

However I should be able to replace the entire sub with:

```
*{"${class}::${tc}"} = $slave->trace;
```

which of course doesn't work because I need a reference to $slave->trace, the code above would just call it. Sadly I also don't understand the use of the glob, or indeed much of the reference stuff on the lvalue. In my defence I can do anything with pointers in C or references in javascript, but perl references are quite a meal. Still learning.

I think OO is the right approach because the the tracer has lots of private data, specifically which trace classes are on for which state, and of course the header for each trace class. Nested objects is also right if I could get the simple assignment above working.

All this is part of me writing a make system for my VHDL project. I forced myself to do it in perl because I thought it was about time I learned the language properly rather than writing 10 line duct tapes.

I now realise *{"${class}::${tc}"} = \&trace->slave probably could never work. Would the first argument be the Tracer instance, or the TraceSlave instance? To work it would have to be TraceSlave instance, but this is a method defined in the Tracer class. Of course I could stick the slaves back in the Tracer $self, but that would make things more not less complicated.

I guess it now does what I want as simply as possible.

Comment: You probably want **my** $slave = TraceSlave->new(...); inside the for loop. The anonymous sub (closure) is closing over $slave, but you're transforming it on every iteration. You want to close over a new slave each time.

Regarding `\&$slave->trace` - you can only take a reference to a sub itself. You should think of `$slave->trace(@args)` as `TraceSlave::trace($slave, @args)`. It's clear that the latter is a method call rather than the method itself. The `sub { ... };` is definitely needed here.

Comment: @Unk Sticking in a "my" made it work. Magic! Actually I do grasp how the my works but the rest is magic to me. I cannot claim to understand how *{"${class}::$tc"} works. In particular why a glob and double quotes are needed. ::${tc} can be simplified to ::$tc why I also don't realise. I see TraceSlave::trace(..) gets no extra parameters while TraceSlave->trace(..) does get the class name. Fascinating. In javascript I'd do window.onload = new Thing(...).loader. Very elegant is js for assigned method references to things that expect same! Sorry pointless observation.